# Configuration problem with LD2410C in esphome

Tags: esphome

I am trying to configure the LD2410C presence sensor with esphome and the configuration is running smoothly but the operation is not as expected. The presence sensor is always ON and the "Moving Targer" and "Still Target" sensors do not stop alternating every second regardless of whether there is someone nearby or not.
I am using an ESP32-WROOM-32 where I have already configured a temperature sensor that works without any problem.

When configuring I used two sets of pins
tx_pin: GPIO17 rx_pin: GPIO16
tx_pin: GPIO27 rx_pin: GPIO26
with the same result in both cases. The power supply goes to the 5v pin of the esp itself.

The yaml configuration file is the one from the esp-home web site as is without changing anything.

```
uart:
  id: uart1
  tx_pin: GPIO17
  rx_pin: GPIO16
  baud_rate: 256000
  parity: NONE
  stop_bits: 1

  ld2410:
  timeout: 150s
  max_move_distance : 6m
  max_still_distance: 0.75m

  ....
```

The same thing happens to me with two LD2410C chips and two different ESPs. Can anyone think what am I doing wrong?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and the problem seems to be in the firmware/configuration from the Esphome, the LD2410 or LD2410B sensor parameters need adjusting. I had the same "always on" output regarding the module used or the esp32 board. With a brand new module after I upload a new firmware from ESPHome the board will output "Presence Detected", although until then worked perfectly.
The temporary solution is to use the HLKRadarTool app for Android or iOS to Initialize the LD2410C module (upper right corner More-Initialize) and afterwards determine the correct parameters from the graphs and adjust the yaml code from ESPHome (especially the below part), or do not reprogram the esp32 with the LD2410C module connected.

```
ld2410:
  timeout: 5s
  max_move_distance : 6m
  max_still_distance: 0.75m
  g0_move_threshold: 50
  g0_still_threshold: 20
  g1_move_threshold: 50
  g1_still_threshold: 20
  g2_move_threshold: 40
  g2_still_threshold: 40
  g3_move_threshold: 30
  g3_still_threshold: 40
  g4_move_threshold: 20
  g4_still_threshold: 30
  g5_move_threshold: 15
  g5_still_threshold: 30
  g6_move_threshold: 15
  g6_still_threshold: 20
  g7_move_threshold: 15
  g7_still_threshold: 20
  g8_move_threshold: 15
  g8_still_threshold: 20
```

Regards,
Sorin.